# What explains the restrictions on determinative "you"?

Tags: grammatical-number, determiners, personal-pronouns, vocatives

As Huddleston & Pullum note, "you" can sometimes be used as a determiner:

> You idiots never learn.
>
> I'll never understand you idiots.

But this generally can't occur in the singular:

> *You idiot never learn.
>
> *I'll never understand you idiot.

But they mention that it *can* be used in the singular as part of a vocative:

> You never learn, you idiot!
>
> You idiot, I'll never understand you!

Is there a reason why the restriction to the plural exists everywhere *except for* the vocative? Or is this just a purely arbitrary rule?

Comment: Well, we do use it in the singular without a verb: You idiot! You fool! etc.

Comment: @Lambie Indeed. That's also a vocative (as H&P note); vocatives can occur without a verb.

Comment: _You_ started off as a plural (singular was _thou_). Perhaps that's a good enough reason to retain it in specific (and rare) circumstances.

Comment: How is this usage of "you" a determiner and not a pronoun?

Comment: Where is it that Huddleston and Pullum note this?

Comment: @TinfoilHat "You" (plural) as a determiner is discussed on p. 374. The vocative use of "you" (singular) as a determiner is mentioned very briefly (with the example "you stupid bastard") on p. 523. H&P don't seem to give any explanation for why vocatives allow for this.

Comment: Why no mention of first person plural ("we/us idiots never learn")?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan — From CGEL: [excepting the vocative exception] *...the personal determiners can only be the 1st person plural **we** and the 2nd person plural **you**..., while all the personal pronouns regardless of person and number occur in the appositional construction.*

Comment: *Why?* ... *Because!* Isn’t that the beauty of descriptive grammar? You might be interested in [this paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~zwicky/hey-whatsyourname.pdf) (see especially p. 798 at end).

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, it's only those two cases, so I was wondering why OP restricted the question only to the latter case while not mentioning the former. Not a big deal; I just thought that it might be worthwhile to mention the other case, too.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan — Probably because a singular vocative *we* is impossible. *\*We’ll never learn, we idiot!*

Comment: @MarcInManhattan "We" allows this determinative use, as do "us" and occasionally "them" in informal speech: ["them people never call you back."](https://genius.com/Bob-airplanes-lyrics)

Comment: FWIW, "thou fool" appears three times in the KJV: twice clearly as a vocative (Luke 12:20 and 1 Corinthians 15:36), and once *probably* as a vocative though there's no context so I can't say for sure (Matthew 5:22). Likewise, *Henry IV, Part 2*, Act II, Scene 1 includes several insults like "thou bastardly rogue", and "thou <noun phrase>" consistently appears there only as a vocative. So this restriction on *you* seems to have a long history.

Comment: Determinative *y'all*, plural or collective, is a part of this 2pl.  This is exactly like when y'all isn't a vocative, subject, or object. When I say to an Australian, "Y'all don't know how it's used, and I'm not talking to you but about you all," this is it. One (plural or collective determinative) never learns without reflecting on experience.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer based upon observable grammatical facts, but not drawn from any published, vetted grammar reference.

Verbs must agree with pronouns occurring as subjects or within subjects:

1. **He is** lucky.
2. **He** who is without blame **is** lucky.
3. Her student couldn't attend. **They were** otherwise engaged.

In (1) and (2) we see the verb *be* agreeing with the pronoun *he.* In (3) we see that the pronoun *they*, as the subject, commands plural verb agreement despite the fact that it is being used to refer to a single person.

However, in NPs with common or proper nouns occurring as the head of the nominal phrase, the verb agrees with that noun in terms of number, and is always third person if the noun is singular. It does not matter who the noun refers to:

4. **Araucaria is** writing you an answer.
5. ***Araucaria am** writing you an answer.

In (4-5) we see that although *Araucaria* refers to me, the writer,  the verb *be* must take a third person singular form, not a first person one. (5) is ungrammatical.

Now, even with the verb *be*, which is more highly inflected than any other English verb, the form of the verb is identical for the first person, second person and third person plural:

6. we **are** happy
7. you both **are** happy
8. they **are** happy

And, as with the pronoun *they*, it does not matter if the pronoun *you* is used to refer to a single person or multiple people:

9. you, my friend, **are** happy

Arguably, an English verb table for *be* should look something like this:

> 1st person singular: ***am***
> 3rd person singular: ***is***
> Plural: ***are***

And it should be understood that *you* in English is always grammatically plural (in terms of grammatical number, not semantics).

**The Original Poster's question**

The Original  Poster asks why we can say both *you idiots* (plural noun), and *you idiot* (singular noun), but only the first of these can occur as a subject.

We noted two points further above. Firstly, a verb must agree with a pronoun in a subject NP. Secondly, an NP with a singular common or proper noun as head must take a third person singular form of the verb.

With the NP *you idiots* these rules don't present a problem:

10. **You idiots are** unbelievable.

However, with the singular *you idiot* we have a problem. The pronoun *you* means that only a plural form of the verb is permitted, but the singular common noun means that only a singular form can be used. The result is that whether we use a singular or plural form of the verb, the result is ungrammatical:

11. ***You idiot** is unbelievable.
12. ***You idiot** are unbelievable.

I deeply suspect that this is at the heart of the problem with using *you idiot* as a subject. However, as Pullum always says: with regard to English grammar, the truth is rarely pure and never simple. My reason for saying this is that *you idiot* is not available as a subject for a non-finite clause either:

13. It was necessary for you idiots to win the tournament.
14. *It was necessary for you idiot to win the tournament.

Such is life ...

Comment: Are you sure 14 is ungrammatical? It is not obvious to me that it is.

Comment: Interesting hypothesis! This doesn't quite explain why "you idiot" also can't be an *object* ("I hate you idiot" sounds wrong to me). One possibility is just that, since the NP can't occur as subject due to this person/number issue, it can't occur anywhere else either. But then you have to ask why it *is* OK in vocatives.

Comment: @Araucaria I believe you mean (5) is ungrammatical, not (4) is ungrammatical.  Great answer so +1 :)

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Oops, yes! Thanks for catching that:)

Comment: @TheZ No, I'm not absolutely sure. It seems to hit my grammar bone, but not hard. (It's better for my tentative theory if it *is* grammatical, of course). Perhaps I should give it a < ? > instead of a < * > .

Comment: @alphabet It can be used as an object like in "I gave you idiot the money yesterday." At least that sounds right to me. But, it does sound unnatural in other cases like the one you mentioned.

Comment: If the example I gave is not grammatical, a plausible alternative theory I just thought of is that it works in every case that the sentence would be grammatical with either word removed. So, "you idiots" works because all sentences with it would be grammatical with either "you" or "idiots" removed, so speakers have an easier time accepting it.

Comment: One other note: it seems that this construction also can't be the subject of an *imperative.* "Don't you idiot go making up excuses!" sounds wrong, at least to me; whereas, as a vocative, "Don't go making up excuses, you idiot!" is obviously correct, as is the plural "Don't you idiots go making up excuses!"

Answer (score 0):

It's just a hypothesis, but it is based on rules that are valid in English and in some European languages, at least in the ones I speak.

I think this inability of "you" to be a determiner in the singular when it is not vocative has to do with DETERMINERS EXCLUDING EACH OTHER. Let me explain.

We all know that some determiners just can't be combined before a noun, as [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-position-and-order) shows:

> ***We don’t use two referring determiners or two quantifying determiners together***:
>
> - *We sold *the our* house.

You will rightfully ask what this has got to do with your question. If you say:

> I can never understand ***you idiots***.

I would analyse *you* as the direct object of *understand* and ***idiots*** as the ***apposition*** of *you* (I know, how preposterous!). So I could understand this sentence as:

> I can never understand ***you [who are] idiots***.

Note that if I made the bold part into a statement on its own, I would say

> You are idiots

NOT

> You are THE idiots.

I am guessing that if you COULD ONLY say "You are the idiots", then "you" would not be able to be a determiner in the plural either.

---

This is what happens in the singular. We can ONLY say

> You are AN idiot

as

> *You are idiot

is ungrammatical.<sup>1</sup>

Since *an idiot* already has a determiner ('an'), it makes sense that it is not possible to add another determiner ('you') before 'idiot':

> *I can never understand *you AN idiot*.<sup>2</sup>

which according to the apposition hypothesis could be re-written as

> I can never understand *you [who are] AN idiot*.

However, in the vocative singular, you can miraculously say, ***without the article "an"***:

> Idiot!

You cannot call a man this name to his face using an article:

> *An idiot!

Therefore, ***You*** can be used before *idiot!* as a determiner, because it does not clash with any other determiners, particularly with *an* in our case.

---

<sup>1</sup> That is, when ***idiot*** is used as a noun, not as an adjective.

<sup>2</sup> Note that we *can* say ***I can't understand you, you idiot!***, where the second "you" is correctly used as a determiner in the vocative.

Comment: Here's one potential complication: why is "I can't understand half you people" OK but "I can't understand half you" wrong? (To my ear, at least. Likewise with "all" instead of "half.") It does seem like "half you people" is valid because "you" is a determiner there and accepts predeterminer modifiers; if it were an appositive, we'd expect "half you" and "half you people" to be equally (in)valid.

Comment: Note that "half" can be combined with articles (half the people), whereas pronouns can't. You cannot say "my the people" or "my a/the friend". I think that's where the issue lies.

Comment: @FEV You can't have two central Determiners. of any description: **some these people* / **a Bob's friend*  / **this a person* / **any the people* etc. This is why **my a friend* is ungrammatical in English :)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, I think this is the point I am making to explain why "you" can't be a determiner in the singular.

Comment: Seems your theory involve treating *you* both as the object and the determiner at the same time, which is interesting but Idk if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

1. You idiots never learn.
2. *You idiot never learn.
3. Idiot! You never learn.
4. The idiot! He never learns.
5. You never learn, you idiot.
6. [O] You idiot! You never learn. (vocative)
7. *O Jesus said that he could walk on water. (vocative cannot be the subject)
8. Murderer! You will hang! (Interjection no determiner)

As a singular countable noun, you would expect “idiot” to take a determiner, however, as an interjection, it does not (3). It is the resemblance of the vocative to an interjection (6) that allows the omission of a determiner, and neither the vocative nor an interjection can be the subject of a sentence. You idiot therefore must be either a vocative or an interjection and cannot be the subject.

Consider also

*I'll never understand you idiot.

I'll never understand, you idiot.

I'll never understand you, idiot.

You idiot, I'll never understand.

Idiot! I'll never understand you.

Idiot, I'll never understand you.

I’ll confess that once again, I have no idea what Pullam and Huddleston are talking about. If they thought that “you” was a determiner, then why did they write *You idiot never **learn**. Verbs do not agree with determiners – it should be * “You idiot never **learns**”

OED gives a very satisfactory explanation that has a pedigree of about 1000 years without being an iconoclast and without a bee in its bonnet.

If you look at the examples above and below, you will see that they all can be seen as having the ellipsis of “who is/are”. However, * “You idiot never learns” requires a determiner with the addition: You who are **an** idiot never learns. The determiner cannot be part of the ellipsis.

There are some examples below where this ellipsis is not immediately apparent, e.g. *Reckons you lot have sold out,* but here, “lot” also has the normal ellipsis = lot of traitors/cowards, or can be implied/defined by some other characteristic that is contextually indicated.

> **You** *(pron.)*
>
> **As object or subject.**    **3. Defined or made precise by a qualifying word or phrase.** Cf. we pron. 1c, us pron. 2.
>
> OE   Ælfric Lives of Saints (Julius) (1881) I. 38   *Ic for Cristes
> lufe forlæt **eow ealle**, and middaneardlice lustas swa swa meox
> forseah.*
>
> 1965   B. Kaufman Up Down Staircase xii. 82   ***You teachers** are
> all alike.*
>
> 1982   P. Redmond Brookside (Mersey TV transmission script) (O.E.D.
> Archive) Episode 5. 46   *Reckons **you lot** have sold out.*
>
> 1994   S. Braude Mpho's Search ix. 50   *As for the rest of **you
> chaps**—scoot—into bed. Lights out in ten minutes.*

> **We** *(pron)*
>
> **1.c. Defined or made precise by a qualifying word or phrase.**
>
> OE   Cynewulf Crist II 746   *Swa **we men** sculon heortan gehygdum
> hlypum styllan of mægne in mægen.*
>
> 1918   Act 8 George V c. 1   ***We**, Your Majesty's most dutiful and
> loyal subjects, **the Commons of the United Kingdom**..in Parliament
> assembled.*
>
> *2003   Chatelaine (Canada) Jan. 20/2   It's what **we psychologists** call cheap peace.*

> **Us** (pron)
>
> **2. In restricted use with defining term added.**
>
> OE   Ælfric Catholic Homilies: 2nd Ser. (Cambr. Gg.3.28) xxxii. 275
> *Eft syððan þæs ælmihtigan godes sunu..asende **us his apostolum** þone
> halgan gast of heofenum on fyres hiwe.*
>
> 1976   W. W. Warner Beautiful Swimmers ii. 21   *A townie named Skeeter
> Yates used to tell **us city kids** that a soft crab was one ‘caught in
> the act’.*
>
> 1989   J. Autry Life after Mississippi i. 3   *Worms or grubs from
> under a wet log turned over by one of **us boys**.*

Comment: So, in vocative "you idiot," what part of speech is "you"?

Comment: In which sentence?

Comment: In "You never learn, you idiot."

Comment: "**You** (nominative singular pronoun) **never learn, you** (nominative singular pronoun probably disjunctive)  **idiot** (noun.)" Compare UK Tyneside dialect "I'm a winner, me" and the French "Tu es gagneur, toi!")

Comment: @Greybeard "I'm a winner, me" is a left dislocation. Quite frequent in standard English too (though not formal, of course!).

Comment: @Greybeard Is your claim that the vocative consists of an ordinary pronoun followed by a noun? Then why is the vocative "you total idiot" OK, when "you the idiot" is wrong?

Comment: @alphabet Possibly: "O you total idiot, take yourself away!" "O you the idiot, take yourself away!"