# "them" vs. "those"

Tags: semantics, semantic-shift

In some places, I have found *them* to be used in a place where it seems to mean as much as *those*. One example is the song *Into the Great Wide Open* by Tom Petty. The chorus has the lines

> Into the great wide open,
> Under them skies of blue

This site already has a [question whether using *them* instead of *those* is "correct"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150674/could-them-mean-those). I am not interested at all in normative debates. Instead, I have a question about the actual use and meaning of this construction, which is not answered in the other question, due to its focus on normative aspects:

Besides the socio-linguistic implications, I wonder whether there are also semantic implications: Does using *them* instead of *those* involve a slightly different meaning? Are there semantics, where *those* and *them* would not be used interchangeably (even by people who use *them* as a replacement for *those* in other situations)?

I have a hypothesis, but I am not at all sure about it. The idea occurred to me that *them* might be used when the referred amount of objects is very vague and unspecific.

But as a non-native speaker of English, I didn't have the opportunity to study the phenomenon in depth, so I am asking here whether someone has more information and can either confirm or disprove my hypothesis. It goes without saying that if there is a semantic difference, but it is not the one stated in my hypothesis, I would be interested in this as well.

Comment: There are certainly places where they aren't interchangeable for syntactic reasons: compare "those of you who..." to "them of you who..." -- I'm pretty sure the latter is wrong.

Comment: (This use of "them" as a determiner is likely patterned after the use of we/you as determiners, e.g. "I hate you idiots.")

Comment: Your tentative theory is not correct, I'm afraid (or at least, it isn't correct in some dialects that use *them* as a determiner). The reason that I can confidently say this is that *them* is often found with numerals, for example: *them two over there*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That is an interesting example I was not even aware of. Is it really a substitute for _those_ here or rather for _they_ or _the_?

Comment: Here's [a paper on this issue.](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/demonstrative-them) This usage appears to be more common in AAVE.

Comment: One note on the above: "these here books" is correct, "them there books" is correct, but "those here/there books" is wrong.

Comment: @alphabet — *those there* is fine.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "Those there Xs" sounds wrong to me; [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+there+boy%2Cthis+here+boy%2Cthese+here+boys%2Cthose+there+boys%2Cthem+there+boys&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) doesn't find it with the word "boys," unlike the other combinations. I'm with Yale on this one.

Comment: A really quick search yielded these: [`those there NOUN`](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/?c=now&q=114006698)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The idea occurred to me that *them* might be used when the referred amount of objects is very vague and unspecific.

It seems much more likely that this is derived from uses of other plural personal pronouns as determiners. Compare:

1. **We** workers will be in charge.
2. They will put **us** workers in charge.
3. **You** fools never learn.
4. We will never support **you** fools.
5. I wanted **them** people to help.

The meanings of such determiners are, of course, derived from those of the corresponding pronouns. Why does this only happen to plural pronouns? [I don't know either.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605187/what-explains-the-restrictions-on-determinative-you)

So here's a question: why does "them" as a determiner appear as a *subject*? I suspect it's because "us" is used in a similar nonstandard way:

1. **Us** workers will be in charge.
2. **Them** people will be in charge.

That said, [The Yale Grammatical Diversity Project English in North America](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/demonstrative-them) notes something interesting. You can say "this here book," "these here books," and "that there book," but "those there books" is very rare. However, "them there books" *is* allowed. This makes it seem like "them" acts a bit more like a demonstrative than one would expect.

Yale also notes that:

> [This usage] is widely attested in Appalachian English (AppE), African American English (AAE), and in certain varieties in the Midland and Southern U.S. (Hazen 2011).

Comment: Why do you think that this derives from other uses of personal pronouns instead of just being another case of a personal pronoun in determiner function?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That's what I meant; sorry if it wasn't clear. My point is that normally this only applies to a  we/us/you; the extension to *them* is often considered nonstandard.